# Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

What I am trying to do? I am trying to display blur colors as a placeholder for my Fastimages component like displaying those blur colors according to the image background if the image is fetching and loading with the help of encode and blue strings I am using for that **[react-native-blurhash](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-blurhash)  **

Can anyone please help me to do that? the package also has an encoding with it [Encoding](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-blurhash#encoding:%7E:text=or%5BQ6.%27)-,Encoding,-This%20library%20also) but it's not working so I used **[blurhash](https://github.com/woltapp/blurhash) **package to do that but it's giving me this error Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented How can I achieve what I am trying to do with my code?

```
const PostCard = ({ postImage }) => {

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [blurhashString, setBlurhashString] = useState(null);
    const source = useMemo(() => ({ uri: postImage }), [postImage]);

    const generateBlurhash = async (postImage) => {
        const response = await fetch(postImage);
        const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();
        const image = await createImageBitmap(imageData);
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
        const imageDataArray = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
        const blurhash = encode(imageDataArray, canvas.width, canvas.height, 4, 4);
        setBlurhashString(blurhash);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        generateBlurhash(postImage);
    }, [postImage]);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                {isLoading && blurhashString ? (
                    <Blurhash
                        blurhash={blurhashString}
                        style={styles.image}
                    />
                ) : (
                    <FastImage
                        source={source}
                        style={styles.image}
                        cache={{
                            immutable: true,
                            cacheLocation: 'high-priority',
                        }}
                        priority={FastImage.priority.high}
                        onLoadEnd={() => setIsLoading(false)}
                    />
                )}
                {isLoading && <ActivityIndicator size='large' color='white' style={styles.spinner} />}
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};
```

Comment: Not sure about the whole process, nor where this error can come from (check your dev-tools you probably have a stack trace you can follow), but note that `createImageBitmap()` does not accept `ArrayBuffer` as input,  you will have to change `const imageData = await response.arrayBuffer();` to `const imageData = await response.blob();`. But once again, I don't think you hit *that* problem just yet.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because react-native's `fetch` implementation cannot handle buffer responses.

There is currently an open pull request to fix this ([here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/30769)), however it has been open for over 2 years so I wouldn't hold my breath.

Another option is to use a library like [axios](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config). You would need to set the `responseType` in your request configuration:

```
    const generateBlurhash = async (postImage) => {
        const response = await axios.get(postImage, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });
        const imageData = response.data;
        const image = await createImageBitmap(imageData);
        // ...rest of your code
```